# Long term liquid food diet by blending/grinding all quality foods one would normaly eat, not any weight loss or prepared drinks

Tags: digestive-system

I want to know what are the effects of not using your teeth to grind foods but preparing it before eating with blending and grinding them into a liquid.

Here I am not talking about any weight loss or fitness industry prepared drinks. I mean the ordinary raw and cooked foods like meat, vegetables, cereals, and fruits that one would normally eat in classic meals.

Would this decrease of work done by teeth and digestion system have positive or negative health effects?

Comment: I would definitely have a negative effect on mood. Why would you deprive yourself from the pleasure of eating a proper meal?

Comment: Don't get me wrong I love eating proper meals, however I don't see pleasure in eating to be my essential need. I could only regard it as an addiction if I needed it to improve my mood. I am only concerned about health effects when helping my body to process food.

Comment: It would probably only be a positive thing -- ultimately, you're increasing surface area of the food particles, which is what our digestive systems try to do anyway in order to absorb the most nutrients.

Comment: @Alexandria: any proof of that? Eating is not merely digesting food for sustainement, it is a much more complex event. What would happen to the secretion of food-related hormones for instance? Would satiety be obtained at the same point? Would you tend to eat less because of the lack of "aesthetic" appeal of liquid food? What would be the effect on the dopaminergic reward systems in the brain? What would be the effect on intestinal microbiota?

Comment: there is a pop nutritional concept of micronutrients, that yes the nutrients would be absorbed into your system more efficiently.  Its a reasonable argument to me.  Still if you are grinding up cheetos and lucky charms you're going to get faster sugar absorption into your system and it should increase the chance of diabetes.  if its broccoli kale and carrots it might help.  if its fewer calories with no meat, even better I think.

Comment: This New Yorker piece on "Soylent" is not peer-reviewed research, but goes into a lot of good, well written detail on the topic, including quotes from nutrition scientists, and anecdotes from users. It might make a good starting point. +1 for a good exploration of the cultural, as well as nutritional issues. http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2014/05/12/the-end-of-food?currentPage=all

Answer (score 2):

I was in a car accident age 19. Jaw was wired shut, food access was limited to one broken front tooth. It was liquid diet or nothing. 
 So, I drank a lot of foods in liquid form, ( soups, etc. ) and a lot of Gerber's baby foods, and just about anything that could be pulverized in a blender. 
 I gained weight like crazy. About 15 pounds in 2 months. 
 The body takes advantage of having the harder work of digestion done for it. One of the advantages of cooking food is it's easier to digest. It is believed by some that such benefits to our life are the reason humans became the dominant force on this planet.

Comment: Well, the only logical explanation for your weight gain is too many calories. The weight gain is not relevant to me because I would control the amount of calories as I do with normal food.